# Scrapy returning scraped values into an array

Tags: python, json, xhtml, scrapy

Scrapy seems to be pulling the data out correctly, but is formatting the output in my JSON object as if it were an array:

```
[{"price": ["$34"], "link": ["/product/product..."], "name": ["productname"]},
{"price": ["$37"], "link": ["/product/product"]...
```

My spider class looks like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    items = sel.select('//div/ul[@class="product"]')
    skateboards = []
    for item in items:
        skateboard = SkateboardItem()
        skateboard['name'] = item.xpath('li[@class="desc"]//text()').extract()
        skateboard['price'] = item.xpath('li[@class="price"]"]//text()[1]').extract()
        skateboard['link'] = item.xpath('li[@class="image"]').extract()
        skateboards.append(skateboard)
    return skateboards
```

How would I go about ensuring that Scrapy is only outputting a single value for each key, rather than the array it's currently producing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.extract()
```

always returns a list you can use

```
''.join(item.xpath('li[@class="desc"]//text()').extract())
```

to get a string

Answer (score 0):

Use: 
1   **.extract_first()**  or 
2   **.extract()[0]**

to get data in string format.

PS: using Scrapy 1.2

Comment: beware ```.extract()[0]``` will returned KeyError Exception if no item on it. its better to use ```extract_first()``` for single item.