# Scrapy's JSON output forms an array of JSON objects

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a games info website using Scrapy. The scraping process goes like this: scraping the categories -> scraping the list of games (multiple pages for each category) -> scraping game info.
The scraped info supposed to go into a json file. I'm getting the following result:

```js
[
    {"category": "cat1", "games": [...]},
    {"category": "cat2", "games": [...]},
    ...
]
```

but I want to get this result:

```js
{ "categories":
    [
        {"category": "cat1", "games": [...]},
        {"category": "cat2", "games": [...]},
        ...
    ]
}
```

I tried to use the steps from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23490643/scrapy-returning-scraped-values-into-an-array) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45158117/scrapy-creating-nested-json-object), with no success. couldn't find more related questions.

I would appreciate any help.

My spider:

```py
import scrapy
from ..items import Category, Game

class GamesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'games'
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.com/categories']
    base_url = 'https://www.exmple.com'

    def parse(self, response):
        categories = response.xpath("...")

        for category in categories:
            cat_name = category.xpath(".//text()").get()
            url = self.base_url + category.xpath(".//@href").get()    
            
            cat = Category()
            cat['category'] = cat_name
            
            yield response.follow(url=url, 
                                  callback=self.parse_category, 
                                  meta={ 'category': cat })

    def parse_category(self, response):
        games_url_list = response.xpath('//.../a/@href').getall()

        cat = response.meta['category']
        url = self.base_url + games_url_list.pop()
        next_page = response.xpath('//a[...]/@href').get()
        
        if next_page:
            next_page = self.base_url + response.xpath('//a[...]/@href').get()

        yield response.follow(url=url, 
                              callback=self.parse_game, 
                              meta={'category': cat, 
                                    'games_url_list': games_url_list, 
                                    'next_page': next_page})
            
    def parse_game(self, response):
        cat = response.meta['category']
        game = Game()

        try:
            cat['games_list']
        except:
            cat['games_list'] = []
        
        game['title_en'] = response.xpath('...')
        game['os'] = response.xpath('...')
        game['users_rating'] = response.xpath('...')
 
        cat['games_list'].append(game)

        games_url_list = response.meta['games_url_list']
        next_page = response.meta['next_page']
        
        if games_url_list: 
            url = self.base_url + games_url_list.pop()
            yield response.follow(url=url, 
                                  callback=self.parse_game, 
                                  meta={'category': cat, 
                                        'games_url_list': games_url_list, 
                                        'next_page': next_page})

        else:
            if next_page:
                yield response.follow(url=next_page, 
                                      callback=self.parse_category, 
                                      meta={'category': cat})
            else:
                yield cat
```

My item.py file:

```py
import scrapy

class Category(scrapy.Item):
    category = scrapy.Field()
    games_list = scrapy.Field()

class Game(scrapy.Item):
    title_en = scrapy.Field()
    os = scrapy.Field()
    users_rating = scrapy.Field()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a custom [item exporter](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#topics-exporters), or handle post-processing of the file generated by Scrapy separately, e.g. with a standalone Python script that converts from the output format to the desired format.