# Fix the formatting of data scraped with Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape jobs on Upwork using the [following URL](https://www.upwork.com/search/jobs/?sort=recency) (I know that they have an API, but they're taking forever to accept my request, so this is my backup solution by now).

I have managed to scrape the data I'm interested in using Scrapy, however, the formatting of the data makes it completely unusable.

Results sample :

```
[
{"jobs": ["<div data-ng-controller=\"JobSearchUI.common.jobs.JobDescriptionController as jobDescriptionController\" data-ng-init='jobDescriptionController.init({\"title\":\"A 10- 15 second high energy animated video advert for an online conference\",\"createdOn\":\"2021-02-14T18:31:46+00:00\",\"type\":1,\"ciphertext\":\"~01dadcd2c0f78d201a\",\"description\":\"I am looking for a talented video editor, animator to create a short, video advert for an online conference. This video will be 10-15 seconds in length and should be dynamic and eye-catching. I am hosting a STEM conference online for teachers and so I would like an advert that I can use on social media to advertise the event. You can find more about the event here: www.stemmena.com. \\n\\nAre you the right person for the job? Have you done something similar in the past? I would like to hear from you.\\n\\nSTEM MENA Online Conference\\n\\nDate: March 16-17, 2021\\n\\nTime: 15:00-19:00 UAE Time ( GMT +4)\\n\\nTheme: Delivering Effective STEM Education In A Changing World\\n\\nLive Panel Discissions          On-Demand STEM Workshops        Live Keynotes\\n\\nInteractive Event App \\n\\nCertificate of Attendance\\n\\nRegister Now!\\n\\nwww.stemmena.com\",\"category2\":null,\"subcategory2\":null,\"skills\":[{\"name\":\"animated-video\",\"prettyName\":\"Animated\",\"highlighted\":false,\"uid\":null},{\"name\":\"background-music\",\"prettyName\":\"Background Music\",\"highlighted\":false,\"uid\":null},{\"name\":\"commercial\",\"prettyName\":\"Commercial\",\"highlighted\":false,\"uid\":null},{\"name\":\"mp4\",\"prettyName\":\"MP4\",\"highlighted\":false,\"uid\":null},{\"name\":\"mpg-file-format\",\"prettyName\":\"MPG\",\"highlighted\":false,\"uid\":null},{\"name\":\"motion-graphics\",\"prettyName\":\"Motion Graphics\",\"highlighted\":false,\"uid\":null},{\"name\":\"animation\",\"prettyName\":\"Animation\",\"highlighted\":false,\"uid\":null},{\"name\":\"3d-animation\",\"prettyName\":\"3D Animation\",\"highlighted\":false,\"uid\":null}],\"duration\":null,\"shortDuration\":null,\"durationLabel\":null,\"engagement\":null,\"shortEngagement\":null,\"amount\":{\"currencyCode\":\"USD\",\"amount\":80},\"recno\":222825632,\"uid\":\"1361020317608943616\",\"client\":{\"paymentVerificationStatus\":1,\"location\":{\"country\":\"United Arab Emirates\"},\"totalSpent\":2969,\"totalReviews\":39,\"totalFeedback\":4.4933615819,\"companyRid\":0,\"companyName\":null,\"edcUserId\":0,\"lastContractPlatform\":null,\"lastContractRid\":0,\"lastContractTitle\":null,\"feedbackText\":\"4.49 Stars, based on 39 feedbacks\",\"companyOrgUid\":\"778226330691952640\",\"hasFinancialPrivacy\":false},\"freelancersToHire\":0,\"relevanceEncoded\":\"{\\\"position\\\":\\\"0\\\"}\",\"enterpriseJob\":false,\"tierText\":\"Expert\",\"tier\":\"Expert\",\"tierLabel\":\"Experience Level\",\"isSaved\":null,\"feedback\":null,\"proposalsTier\":\"Less than 5\",\"isApplied\":false,\"sticky\":false,\"stickyLabel\":\"\",\"jobTs\":\"1613327506138\",\"prefFreelancerLocationMandatory\":false,\"prefFreelancerLocation\":[],\"premium\":false,\"plusBadge\":null,\"publishedOn\":\"2021-02-14T18:31:46+00:00\",\"renewedOn\":null,\"sandsService\":null,\"sandsSpec\":null,\"sandsAttrs\":null,\"occupation\":null,\"attrs\":[{\"parentSkillUid\":null,\"freeText\":null,\"skillType\":3,\"uid\":\"1031626712944197632\",\"highlighted\":false,\"prettyName\":\"Animated\"},{\"parentSkillUid\":null,\"freeText\":null,\"skillType\":3,\"uid\":\"1045317610177069056\",\"highlighted\":false,\"prettyName\":\"Background Music\"},{\"parentSkillUid\":null,\"freeText\":null,\"skillType\":3,\"uid\":\"1045317619215794176\",\"highlighted\":false,\"prettyName\":\"Commercial\"},{\"parentSkillUid\":null,\"freeText\":null,\"skillType\":3,\"uid\":\"1045317665298612224\",\"highlighted\":false,\"prettyName\":\"MP4\"},{\"parentSkillUid\":null,\"freeText\":null,\"skillType\":3,\"uid\":\"1356688481079005184\",\"highlighted\":false,\"prettyName\":\"MPG\"},{\"parentSkillUid\":null,\"freeText\":null,\"skillType\":3,\"uid\":\"1031626760797011968\",\"highlighted\":false,\"prettyName\":\"Motion Graphics\"},{\"parentSkillUid\":null,\"freeText\":null,\"skillType\":3,\"uid\":\"1052162208776900617\",\"highlighted\":false,\"prettyName\":\"Animation\"},{\"parentSkillUid\":null,\"freeText\":null,\"skillType\":3,\"uid\":\"1031626786411626496\",\"highlighted\":false,\"prettyName\":\"3D Animation\"}],\"isLocal\":false,\"workType\":null,\"locations\":[],\"occupations\":{\"category\":{\"uid\":\"531770282580668421\",\"prefLabel\":\"Design &amp; Creative\"},\"subcategories\":[{\"uid\":\"1356688570056970240\",\"prefLabel\":\"Video &amp; Animation\"}],\"oservice\":{\"uid\":\"1017484851352698982\",\"prefLabel\":\"Video Production\"}},\"weeklyBudget\":null,\"hourlyBudgetText\":null,\"tags\":[],\"clientRelation\":null})' class=\"m-md-bottom d-none d-lg-block\">\n        <div class=\"description break\">\n            <div class=\"d-none d-xl-block\" data-eo-truncation-html-unsafe=\"jobDescriptionController.description\" data-eo-chars-threshold=\"380\" data-eo-on-truncation-toggle=\"jobDescriptionController.eoOnDescriptionTruncationToggle\" data-key=\"~01dadcd2c0f78d201a\" data-relevance='{\"position\":\"0\"}' data-is-open=\"isOpen[222825632]\">\n                I am looking for a talented video editor, animator to create a short, video advert for an online conference. This video will be 10-15 seconds in length and should be dynamic and eye-catching. I am hosting a STEM conference online for teachers and so I would like an advert that I can use on social media to advertise the event. You can find more about the event here: www.stemmena.com. \n\nAre you the right person for the job? Have you done something similar in the past? I would like to hear from you.\n\nSTEM MENA Online Conference\n\nDate: March 16-17, 2021\n\nTime: 15:00-19:00 UAE Time ( GMT +4)\n\nTheme: Delivering Effective STEM Education In A Changing World\n\nLive Panel Discissions          On-Demand STEM Workshops        Live Keynotes\n\nInteractive Event App \n\nCertificate of Attendance\n\nRegister Now!\n\nwww.stemmena.com\n            </div>\n            <div class=\"d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none\" data-eo-truncation-html-unsafe=\"jobDescriptionController.description\" data-eo-chars-threshold=\"320\" data-eo-on-truncation-toggle=\"jobDescriptionController.eoOnDescriptionTruncationToggle\" data-key=\"~01dadcd2c0f78d201a\" data-relevance='{\"position\":\"0\"}' data-is-open=\"isOpen[222825632]\">\n
```

Is there a way to flatten this json file ? Should I just change the code I'm using to scrape the information ?

For reference, here's the xPath I'm using to get the results.

```
jobs = response.xpath("//div[@class='m-md-bottom d-none d-lg-block']").getall()
```

Thank you so much for your help !

Comment: I started, used lxml but I didn't complete. I think this will help you! https://pastebin.com/9DbuaHr7

Comment: hey, thanks for your solution ! I have tried it, but unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. Here are the different error messages I got : "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testcodeso.py", line 7, in <module>
    doc = lxml.html.fromstring(response.content)
AttributeError: module 'lxml' has no attribute 'html' " https://ibb.co/J3dM8x3

Comment: I fixed those errors. Try now: https://pastebin.com/YXQTbsuG

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, but I'm getting the same results that I was getting before... Maybe I should try with Selenium instead !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66310656/939364